# How to properly sanitize a list of items received from server using RX | filter{} map{}

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

I have the following code which I am trying to use for two purposes:

1) Call an API and get result as a POJO

2) Sanitize this object (POJO) before I display it in the UI

```
   private fun getWinbackDataItems(rewardPurpose: String) /*Single<WinbackBaseItem>*/ {
        val x = repository.getRewardsList(rewardPurpose)
            .filter {
                it.result?.rewards != null
            }.map { winback ->
           winback.result?.rewards?.asSequence()?.filter { rewardsItem ->
                rewardsItem?.id != null && rewardsItem.title != null
            }?.toList()?.take(3)?.map {
                WinbackListItem(it?.id, it?.title!!, false)
            }?.toList()
        }
    }
```

The point of contention for me is the line below:

```
 itemListSanitized.add(WinbackListItem(it.id, it.title, false))
```

At this point I assume the filter has removed all nulls from the original list but to my amazement I find that I have to null check on it and all its content while adding them to the new list.

What do I miss here, pardon my naivety as I have just begun reactive

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  The first thing one of us is missing is how this code is ever going to get to the point of executing the "point of contention".  This stream operation does not end in a terminal operation, so it isn't going to do anything at all.  This says to me that you haven't actually run this code.  So then how do you know that you'll end up having to "null check on it and all its contents"?  Looking at this code, I don't see how, once you add a terminal and the code does something, `it.id` or `it.title`  could ever be `null` when the line you say is problematic is executed.

Comment: ...ahh...you changed your code!  Ok, I'll think about it again...

Comment: You still have the same problem.  This code isn't going to run either, as the outer stream operation still has no terminal operation.

Comment: I take it that you are working not against executing code but against your IDE's messages or just the ability for this code to compile.  What you're probably running up against is that earlier checks for `null` won't necessarily allow the compiler to assume non-null values, because in the meantime, other code in a different thread could have run and changed the values.

Comment: Thanks @Steve, yes you are right, as you see I have commented out the return type on my method; because I am not actually running the code but trying to form it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it that you are working not against executing code but against your IDE's warning messages or just the ability for this code to compile.  What you're probably running up against is that earlier checks for `null` won't necessarily allow the compiler to assume non-null values later on, because in the meantime, other code in a different thread could have run and changed the values.

So when you create a WinbackListItem, you can safely assume that certain items are not null, and yet the compiler can't be sure of this, because it can't know what else is going on in your process space.  So the compiler requires that you tell it not to worry about null values (!!) or that you check the values again.  This is just the way Kotlin works.  It's often a PITA, but it's just how it is.

I played with the posted code just to be sure I knew what I was talking about.  Here is code that I was able to run:

```
private fun getWinbackDataItems(rewardPurpose: String) /*Single<WinbackBaseItem>*/ {
    val x = repository.getRewardsList(rewardPurpose)
        .filter {
            it.result?.rewards != null
        }.map { winback ->
            winback.result?.rewards?.asSequence().filter { rewardsItem ->
                rewardsItem.id != null && rewardsItem.title != null
            }.toList().take(3).map {
                println(it.id)
                println(it.title)
                WinbackListItem(it.id!!, it.title!!, false)
            }.toList()
        }.count()
}
```

I created some very simple classes and objects to satisfy this code and let it run.  Note that I took out some unnecessary '?' null checks.  I played with input values until I was convinced that `it.id` and `it.title` can never be `null` when the WinbackListItem constructor is called.  And yet, the two `!!` on its parameters, or something else making sure they are not `null`, are required given this definition of WinbackListItem that won't accept `null` parameter values:

```
class WinbackListItem(val id: Int, val title: String, val huh: Boolean)
```

Comment: Your answer is assuring, because I will have to use (!!) seemingly was an antipattern in kotlin and got me thinking. With your assumption of me fighting against compiler warnings you've stuck the right chords!

Comment: Coolio.  I decided to actually play with your code to be sure I knew what I was talking about.  I constructed a minimal set of classes and objects to let your code actually run.   I confirmed as best I could that there was no way for `it.id` and `it.title` to ever be null.  This seems to be true, and yet as you see, `!!` is required on both the final values if the WinbackListItem constructor won't take null values.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the pain with me :)

Comment: Happy to do so :) . Glad I could help.  I've been in on a number of discussions about this sort of thing...how to avoid null checks when you know that things can't be null.  There are third party extensions that help with this, and there are also proposals in the language threads for new constructs in the language to help.  These discussions often involve looking at the resulting Java code.  What happens is that values get moved into temp vars to make sure they won't change.  If the language doesn't support doing this for you, you can always do the same thing yourself...

Comment: If you move something into a local variable, Kotlin can then be sure that nothing else can change the value, and you won't need the `null` checks...just a different sort of pain.

Comment: Actually I've just started with kotlin as well(peer pressure); being a Java first guy, I think this wouldn't even be a problem. Its 4 am in the morning here and I really really appreciate the detail with which you have addressed this question. Wish I could buy you a coffee :)

Comment: I LOVE Kotlin over Java.  My company looked at Groovy as well.  It would have been a good choice too.  The main reason we went with Kotlin is that both IntelliJ and Spring fully support it at a level equal to Java.  This fact outweighed some of the complaints about the language.  It isn't a perfect language, but then there probably will never be such a thing.  Kotlin lets you code faster and produce fewer bugs, especially avoiding NPE exceptions.  So it's a big win in my book...definitely worth getting over the learning curve to take full advantage of it.

Comment: I'm going to go make myself a Latte (seriously).  I'll consider it as having come from you!  Thanks for your kind words.  They very much help motivate me to keep helping people like this when so much of S.O. has turned into people telling each other what they did wrong in how they posed either a question or an answer.